# Unable to Configure Cloudant Data Proxy on MobileFirst container on Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobilefirst, cloudant

I am trying to configure MF container to use Cloudant. And query clouding from the mobile app through the data proxy.

- I followed the instructions in to configure the data proxy on the container:
  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/t_configure_data_proxy.html
- I configured the file /ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval/mfpf-server/usr/env/server.env to have the following value:

  ```
  publicKeyServerUrl=HTTP_CONTAINER_PUBLIC_IP_PORT/MF_PROJECT_CONTEXT_ROOT
  ```
- And the file /ibm-mfpf-container-7.1.0.0-eval/mfpf-server/usr/config/dataproxy.xml to have the following value:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <!-- Licensed Materials - Property of IBM 5725-I43 (C) Copyright IBM Corp.
    2015, 2015. All Rights Reserved. US Government Users Restricted Rights -
    Use, duplication or disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with
    IBM Corp. -->

  <server description="new server">
      <!-- Enable features -->
      <featureManager>
          <!-- Data proxy features -->

          <feature>jaxrs-1.1</feature>
          <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
          <feature>usr:OAuthTai-1.0</feature>        
         <!-- --> 
      </featureManager>

      <!-- OAuth TAI For Data Proxy -->

      <!--OAuth TAI For Data Proxy. -->
      <usr_OAuthTAI cacheSize="1000" id="myOAuthTAI">
          <securityConstraint httpMethods="All" securedURLs="datastore" scope="cloudant"/>
      </usr_OAuthTAI>
      <!-- -->   


      <!--  -->
      <webApplication contextRoot="datastore" id="imf-data-proxy" location="imf-data-proxy.war" name="imf-data-proxy">
          <application-bnd>
              <security-role name="TAIUserRole">
                  <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
              </security-role>
          </application-bnd>
          <classloader delegation="parentLast">
              <commonLibrary>
                  <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil*.jar"/>
              </commonLibrary>
          </classloader>
      </webApplication>
       <!-- -->


       <!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the MobileFirst Data Proxy. 
            Note: These jndi properties are not required if a bluemix app is bound to the container when startserver.sh or startservegroup.sh is executed.
                  Also, uncomment the entry publicKeyServerUrl in server.env and fill in the correct URL.
       <jndiEntry jndiName="datastore/CloudantProxyDbAccount" value='"hostname"'/>
       <jndiEntry jndiName="datastore/CloudantProtocol" value='"http"'/>
       <jndiEntry jndiName="datastore/CloudantPort" value='"80"'/>
       <jndiEntry jndiName="datastore/CloudantProxyDbAccountUser" value='"cloudantuser"'/>
       <jndiEntry jndiName="datastore/CloudantProxyDbAccountPassword" value='"cloudantpassword"'/>
       -->
  </server>
  ```
- Then I ran the scripts prepareserver and start server.
- When I open `http://CONTAINER_PUBLIC_IP:9080/datastore` I get the following response, which seems fine:
  {"imfdata":"ok","version":"1.0"}
- I ran the bluelist sample on this container and I am not able to get it running. It throws the following exception:

> 2015-10-08 00:05:34.055 bluelist-objective-c[37850:708865] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Fatal Exception from Proxy', reason: 'Could not create remote database todosdb.  Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcf72e6efa0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=IP_PF_CONTAINER:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/todosdb, NSErrorFailingURLKey= IP_PF_CONTAINER:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/todosdb, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=HTTP_CONTAINER_PUBLIC_IP_PORT/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/todosdb, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/todosdb, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}'

- This is thrown from the iPhone simultator running this code:

  ```
  [manager remoteStore:dbname completionHandler:^(CDTStore *store, NSError *error) {...
  ```
- I have set cloudantProxyURL in the Objective C code to the following:

  ```
  CONTAINER_PUBLIC_IP:9080/MF_PROJECT_CONTEXT_ROOT
  ```

Any idea where the problem is? I wan to troubleshoot without security. Can I make unauthenticated calls to Cloudant through the IMFDataManager API and data proxy? Or user has to be authenticated?

===============

I could enforce authentication by calling an adapter before calling [manager remoteStore], and authentication is successful. I still get an error 
when I run the following code to connect to a DB on Cloudant and query from it. [manager remoteStore] is the one that throws the error:

IMFDataManager *manager = [IMFDataManager initializeWithUrl:@"HTTP_HOST_PORT/datastore"];

```
// Get reference to data manager
//manager = [IMFDataManager sharedInstance];

NSString *dbname = @"orders_db";

// Create remote store
[manager remoteStore:dbname completionHandler:^(CDTStore *store, NSError *error) {
    if(error){
        // Handle error
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }else{
        CDTStore *remotedatastore = store;
        NSLog(@"Successfully created store");
    }
}];
```

I am getting this error:

2015-10-09 02:14:39.029 bluelist-objective-c[2655:52223] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa270c27270 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey={url = http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db}}}, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db} {
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db";
    NSErrorFailingURLStringKey = "http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1012 \"(null)\" UserInfo={_kCFURLErrorAuthFailedResponseKey={url = http://134.168.13.219:9080/datastore/api/v1/apps/default/orders_db}}";
}

=====

Another point, when I login to the container using SSH and display the server.xml in /opt/ibm/wlp/usr/servers/worklight/server.xml I don't find the lines for OAuth TAI added. There are not there at all.

Comment: I have a couple of questions.

-What kind of authentication are you using? (authentication is required to create the backend DBs from Cloudant)

-I assume you are using Bluelist. What version of the app are you using? Where did you download it from? 

Also I noticed you scrubbed your IPs above but seems you missed one in the last error message.

Comment: I use the latest version https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/mfp-bluelist-on-premises/overview?cm_mc_uid=45918071636414060262056&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1444288616

The authentication is adapter based authentication that veifies fictions name (james, 42).

Thank you for the hint, I scrubbed the IPs because of this validation before posting to make the URLs less than two.

Comment: You should try the latest version which is hosted on github here:

Tutorial: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/data/working-with-cloudant-nosql-db-api/
Sample:
https://github.com/MobileFirst-Platform-Developer-Center/BlueList-On-Premise

Comment: @Jaalger I don't think this is the problem. I could authenticate now but the same code fails. The one that created the remote store I mentioned above.

Comment: I have edited the question. I am wondering where is IBM Bluemix Support who are active here !!!!! This is quite important and the containers simply don't work!!

Comment: Then you need to open a support ticket. This is a community.

Comment: @idan Bluemix doesn't have formal support like other ibm products. I was told here is where you can get the required support. So you as ibm support, have any input on the problem from mobilefirst point of view?

Comment: @AhmedAbdel-Hamid do you still see timeout errors? or is the second error you posted the most recent?

Comment: Yeah @DaveCariello. This is the last exception I am getting. No timeout now.

Answer (score 0):

The above exception indicates that the authorization to access the data proxy component is not successful.

Can you modify the dataproxy.xml to provide the right securedUrls parameter. The value for securedURLs should be "/datastore/*" instead of "datastore". The updated snippet is here :

```
<usr_OAuthTAI cacheSize="1000" id="myOAuthTAI">
    <securityConstraint httpMethods="All" securedURLs="/datastore/*" scope="cloudant"/>
</usr_OAuthTAI>
```

Let me know if the dataproxy works fine using this.